# Uploaded layers are not displayed in QGIS Cloud

Tags: qgis-cloud

I have a free account to QGIS cloud. I tried to upload a project with 3 layers(1 line and 2 polygons). During the process, the plugin shows that all the layers are uploading, but in the end when the uploading ends and i save the project, the 2 polygon layers are missing. You can see their titles in the legend, but not on screen,same thing in the QGIS and in the QGIS cloud map viewer. What can be done?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my question,after some search I did, I found a solution. The problem is from the text language I use (gr). I saved the .shp files with Latin names and saved them at the home folder, and now they are uploading and appearing fine.

Answer (score -2):

Try to delete the fields with 'fid' name.